# knockoutjs and csrf

Tags: knockout.js, csrf

What is the standard method of preventing csrf attacks on a knockout.js application? There are no forms to send over hidden csrf fields to the client. Do you always setup the app to get/request a csrf token before running a new post/request that contains that token?

Comment: Can you be more specific about this problem? I think most folks understand CSRF attacks on a very basic level. The problem with this question is it's unclear to me how KnockoutJS plays any role in these attacks.

Comment: What usually happens is a hidden csrf_token is placed in every form.  When the app is only one page - that means there's only one token.  Right now I put a token into that one page and check any posts have that token submitted too.  I just wish knockoutjs tutorials would address it with at least one example.

Comment: You wrote that there are no form tags in the HTML, but you certainly can (and should) add the form tag(s) yourself, and include the token and the data-bound elements inside your forms.